# Airdropped .avi between OSX 10.10 and iOS 8 not found

Tags: ios, macos, airdrop

I just used Airdrop to transfer a .avi file between OSX 10.10 and iOS 8. After that I can't locate file in iOS. I searched it in Videos and Photos. Where is it? And how I can delete it if I can't use it?

Comment: Did you accept the transfer on the iOS device by tapping?

Comment: Yes I did and file was transfered without error

Answer (score 1):

You can only send and receive iOS-compatible video files such as .m4v, etc.

Comment: This is not true--clearly OP stated that he/she successfully received it, and is just having trouble finding it

Comment: I'm guessing the file was discarded after iOS couldn't find an app to open it. AirDropped files open automatically in the appropriate app, if one exists. You don't just "browse" to them, as far as I know.